# how to fill DataGridView from DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to fill unbounded datagridview with two custom columns and some rows that filled  from a datatable.
first datagridview's column must fill from first datatable column and so on.
first column is name of brand and second is picture of brand.

i use this code and some linq to prepare two arrays

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = clsTransmit.FillDataTable("SELECT brandName, brandPic FROM brands", false);

int count = dt.Rows.Count;
string[] names = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("brandName")).ToArray();
string[] pics = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("brandPic")).ToArray();
```

now i want to fill my datagridview that i already try these codes :

```
DataGridViewColumn brandName = new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
dgv.Columns.Add(brandName);
dgv.Columns.Add(imageCol);
dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Brand Name";
dgv.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Brand Picture";

DataGridViewRow n = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewRow p = new DataGridViewRow();

for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++)
{
    n.Cells[i].Value = names[i];
    p.Cells[i].Value = imgList.Images[i];
}

dgv.Rows.AddRange(n);
dgv.Rows.AddRange(p);
```

and i also try this:

```
dgv.Rows.Add(names);
dgv.Rows.Add(pics);
```

after run an error message is displayed:

> index was out of range.

---

ok update my code and got answer 
i use an image list and fill it by this :

```
foreach (var item in pics)
  {
       Image img = Image.FromFile(item);
       imgList.Images.Add(img);
  }
```

and use these code to fill gridview and got correct answer:

```
dgv.Columns.Add("brandName", "Brand Name");

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
      dgv.Rows.Add(new object[] {names[i]});
}

DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
dgv.Columns.Add(imageCol);
dgv.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Brand Logo";
dgv.Rows.Add();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
      dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = imgList.Images[i];
}
```

but i have another problem now
the problem is the datagridview has extra empty row at bottom of all rows . i already uncheck enable adding, editing, deleting  datagridview but still it has an extra row :(

Comment: My code is not such complicated. As I said, you should not add columns to your `DataGridView` manually, instead using `DataSource`. The code I posted just has a little `IO`, a little `LINQ`, and a little usage of `DataGridView`, you should try it out and understanding it gradually.

Comment: So what's the problem in your updated code?

Comment: Remove the line `dgv.Rows.Add();`

Comment: yes! thanks to you i use `dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(count);` and now i have a clean gridview :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show your images in the `DataGridViewImageColumn`, you have to set-up your data like this:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Picture", typeof(byte[]));
var actualData = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(row=> {
                       row.SetField<byte[]>("Picture", GetBytesFromImagePath(row.Field<string>("brandPic"));
                       return row;
                    }).CopyToDataTable();
actualData.Columns.Remove("brandPic");
dgv.DataSource = actualData;

//Use this method to get byte[] data from the image path
private byte[] GetBytesFromImagePath(string imagePath){
   using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
     Image img = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
     img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
     return ms.GetBuffer();
   }
}
//Set-up Header Text
dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Brand Name";
dgv.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Brand Picture";
```

**NOTE**: You don't need to add columns to your `dgv` manually, just set the `DataSource` as in my code.

If you save `URL` to images instead of `local filepath`, you can modify the code like this:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Picture", typeof(byte[]));
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
int i = 0;
client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("brandPic")), dt.Rows[0]);
client.DownloadDataCompleted += (se, e) => {
   ((DataRow)e.UserState).SetField<byte[]>("Picture", e.Result);
   if(++i == dt.Rows.Count) return;               
   client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(dt.Rows[i].Field<string>("brandPic")), dt.Rows[i]);
};            
dt.Columns.Remove("brandPic");
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: @user1592474 don't thank too soon, you just need to try the code and give some feedback so that I can improve the answer. I'm pretty sure it works. BTW, your code has many things wrong, you use a `DataGridViewImageColumn` but your `brandPic` seems to be `string` referring to image file paths or urls, you passed in the `Row index` into `.Cells[...]` which needs some `Column index` making your `IndexOutOfRangeException`, ... anyway your code is too messy and the solution is use a totally new code with new approach as posted in my answer.

Comment: dear king king your method is too complicated for me and i wrote light method but have another problem that i mentioned on my post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to king king's help i found my answer

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = clsTransmit.FillDataTable("SELECT brandName, brandPic FROM brands", false);

int count = dt.Rows.Count;
string[] names = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("brandName")).ToArray();
string[] pics = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("brandPic")).ToArray();

foreach (var item in pics)
{
   Image img = Image.FromFile(item);
   imgList.Images.Add(img);
}

dgv.Columns.Add("brandName", "Brand Name");

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   dgv.Rows.Add(new object[] {names[i]});
}

DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
dgv.Columns.Add(imageCol);
dgv.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Brand Logo";
dgv.Rows.Add();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = imgList.Images[i];
}
dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(count);
```